# Use multiple databases in Django having the other database contain tables not created by any model

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

Here are my questions and if you want to know the details, kindly refer further below (Sorry for the long post, I wanted the inquiry to be as detailed as possible):

**Questions**

1. Is it possible to retrieve data from an external database and use those inside your Django project even if the tables in that database are NOT created as models? If so, what's the basic concept to achieve such.
2. If NOT, then the workaround left is to use the SAME DATABASE as the remote one, and save all models of the django project into a specific schema in that database?

   ---

So we are trying to forcibly implement `Cross-database referencing` with a remote database `my_remote_db`, that contains tables which are not created by a Django model.

We've read the Django doc telling it currently cannot handle such referencing method, but the fact we can define multiple databases in `settings.py` makes us optimistic that there is somehow a workaround.

**Databases as defined in our settings.py**

- **django_project_db** - main database (the one used by our Django project for its models)
- **my_remote_db** - the remote database. Several applications are using this database e.g. our Scout and PHP applications, etc.

[image]

**What we want to achieve:**

Retrieve data from a remote database (with tables NOT created as `model`) and use those information within our Django project.

**Sample usage:**

Suppose we want to create a model `LeaveRequest` in our Django project that contains a field called `employee` whose value is the employee's `id` referenced from the remote database in `my_remote_db.my_schema.employees` table.

In the admin portal, when adding a new leave request, we want the `employee` field to be a dropdown of employees.

Since it is not possible to use `models.ForeignKey` due to the fact that the remote database's tables are not created as models, we'd then want to just pre-populate the `employee` field by executing raw SQL command and pass the result as `choices[('value','text')}` e.g. `employee = models.IntegerField(choices[('1','Leonard Hofstadter'),('2','Sheldon Cooper')]`

**P.S.**

We've tried running the following in python shell and we would get

> NotSupportedError: cross-database references are not implemented:
>   "my_remote_db.my_schema.employees"

```
from django.db import connection
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute("SELECT first_name FROM my_remote_db.my_schema.employees WHERE id=1")
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    print(row)
```

**ADDITIONAL NOTES:**

The remote database will be used alongside our other applications and would perform all CRUD operations. The remote DB is not a legacy DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging deep, I was able to figure out a solution. `inspectdb` wouldve been a workaround if only our remote DB is a legacy but it isn't. So, we've went over the [DB router](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/multi-db/#using-routers) guide again which solves the problem. Then we were able to communicate the data from the remote DB into our Django app by executing custom SQL directly as per the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly).

We thought the DB router is only applicable if you have another Django app whose database you want to use in another Django app as remote DB.

Comment: Great solution here. I would remember this approach.

Answer (score 0):

You should treat the external database as a legacy DB. In that case you *must* implement models of that DB using `inspectdb` command. 
The roadmap would be:

1. Connect the external db
2. Reverse engineer remote models using `inspectdb`
3. `migrate` to create additional django tables like permissions

Check out the [official django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/legacy-databases/) to get along with it.

Comment: Hmmm this is actually great given that the remote DB is an old one that is already not being used or a 'legacy' as termed above. Problem though is that our remote db is currently being developed too, alongside our other applications and will be used alongside our Django project once both of them are deployed for live use. This is a problem as we would need to run `inspectdb` and encounter `migration constraints` every time a table structure is updated.

Comment: Another problem is that let us say more data will be added into the `employees` table in remote DB, since we are referencing to that table in our Django app using inspectdb then perform migrate, then we would need to periodically sync the data of that table from the remote to Django app db.

Comment: Oh, I got it. Actually it's a bad approach to make direct queries to the other app's database. I would consider to make an API from the other app to retrieve records. In this case you can ensure stability of the system.